# tabulator no element found matching selector

Tags: tabulator

trying first super basic tabulator and getting stuck with console error "no element found matching selector". I've tried a couple different examples, can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.  is this how naming is supposed to work?

```
<html>
<head><title>Test for tabulator</title>
<link href="dist/css/tabulator.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script type="text/javascript" src="dist/js/tabulator.min.js"></script>
<script>
//define data
var tabledata = [
    {id:1, name:"Oli Bob", location:"United Kingdom", gender:"male", rating:1, col:"red", dob:"14/04/1984"},
    {id:2, name:"Mary May", location:"Germany", gender:"female", rating:2, col:"blue", dob:"14/05/1982"},
    {id:3, name:"Christine Lobowski", location:"France", gender:"female", rating:0, col:"green", dob:"22/05/1982"},
    {id:4, name:"Brendon Philips", location:"USA", gender:"male", rating:1, col:"orange", dob:"01/08/1980"},
    {id:5, name:"Margret Marmajuke", location:"Canada", gender:"female", rating:5, col:"yellow", dob:"31/01/1999"},
    {id:6, name:"Frank Harbours", location:"Russia", gender:"male", rating:4, col:"red", dob:"12/05/1966"},
    {id:7, name:"Jamie Newhart", location:"India", gender:"male", rating:3, col:"green", dob:"14/05/1985"},
    {id:8, name:"Gemma Jane", location:"China", gender:"female", rating:0, col:"red", dob:"22/05/1982"},
    {id:9, name:"Emily Sykes", location:"South Korea", gender:"female", rating:1, col:"maroon", dob:"11/11/1970"},
    {id:10, name:"James Newman", location:"Japan", gender:"male", rating:5, col:"red", dob:"22/03/1998"},
];

//define table
var table = new Tabulator("#example-table", {
    data:tabledata,
    autoColumns:true,
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<h1>test tabulator </h1>
<div id="example-table"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

is there something obvious I'm missing? this is copied/pasted right from the samples.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, because the element does not exist when you accessed it. Move your javascript after the div and it should work. Or use the page load event:

#### Bottom page:

```
<div id="example-table"></div>
<script>
var table = new Tabulator("#example-table", {
            data:tabledata,
            autoColumns:true,
        });
</script>
```

#### Page Load:

```
window.addEventListener("load", function() {
    var table = new Tabulator("#example-table", {
        data:tabledata,
        autoColumns:true,
    });
},false);
```

Comment: thanks.  Guess I needed to be reminded that javascript isn't my native language. thanks for your patience!